# PCLStorage on UWP throws an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Working on a project in Xamarin.Forms, and using PCLStorage for file access.
(NuGet is installed in every project - PCL, Droid and UWP).

Code snippet:

```
using PCLStorage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

IFolder root = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

IFile outf = await root.CreateFileAsync("TEST.TXT", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await outf.WriteAllTextAsync("SOME TEXT");

// Here it throws an exception
if (ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists == await root.CheckExistsAsync("TEST.TXT") )
    Debug.WriteLine("File TEST.TXT exists");
else
    Debug.WriteLine("File TEST.TXT NOT found");
```

Every time I try to execute this (in UWP project), I am getiing an unhandled exception with message

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
0x80070057
```

CreateFileAsync actually creates a file, WriteAllTextAsync writes to file, and then, CheckExistsAsync throws an exception.

Now, when I execute it in a debugger step-by-step, *most* of the time it works fine, but *sometimes* it throws an exception, which leads me to beleive that it has something to do with async/threading...

To baffle me more, exact same code works on Android flawlesly.
Spent whole day yesterday trying to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to replicate the issue with no success. Which version of the package you're currently using? Which version of Xamarin.Forms? Are you testing on a real device or an emulator?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms: 2.3.4.247
PCLStorage: 1.0.2
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.1.0+26403.7
.NET Framework 4.6.01586

Testing on real device (Windows 10 Pro)

Comment: Is there any other action happening at the same time? I couldn't replicate this issue in a empty Xamarin.Forms project using your code and package versions.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. 
I do get an infamous "**Warning IDE0006** Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled." But that is for Android project, which is working ok.

Comment: Well, I rewrote the whole file i/o using interface class and implementation by DependencyService, as Xamarin suggests. I guess this will remain unsolved for me. I may revisit someday to figure that out.